# How to get the response in the onPostExecute?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a response in the onPostExecute method. The aim is to display an AlertDialog after testing the result value so, I’ve done it in the doInBackground but isn't logic I suppose? And I’ve think to do it in the onPostExecute but still have no idea how i can get the response.Ther is my code

```
//@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success/*,String result*/) {
        //LoginTask = null;
        //showProgress(false);
        //delegate.processFinish(result);

        if (success) {
           /* AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Succes !");
            builder.setMessage("your new password has been sent to the email address you specified. \nThink to change it later!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();*/
            finish();
        } else {
            //password.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            //password.requestFocus();
            /*AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Error !");
            builder.setMessage("This email does not exist")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();*/

        }

    }
```

Comment: OnPost and OnPre is designed for doing UI operations and doInBackground for backend operations

Comment: but it does not answer to my question

Comment: Please post more code. Why is @Override commented out?

Comment: You obtain your result as a parameter in the onPost then you do your decision according to result, please read the tutorial from this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use async like this:

```
public class asy extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do your work,and return result in string
        //you can send null if not success else return string
        if(your work was true)
            return result;
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //do any thing with result
        if(result == null){
            //not success
        }else{
            //success
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have an error : super.onPostExecute(result); result should be a boolean and not a string

Comment: yes you can use boolean but I see that you need string too,so you can use this for both of your target.if you don't need string as result you can use some thing like above answer

Answer (score 0):

> remember use Boolean (wrapper class) not boolean data type

```
public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //your background code
        if(background code is true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result == true){
            //success
        }else if(result == false{
            //not success
        }
    }

}
```